# Missing gtk_menu_popup_at_pointer()

Tags: gtk, glib, vala, vapi

I am writing a Gtk program in Vala that uses a `Gtk.Menu`. 
I need to use [`Gtk.Menu.popup_at_pointer()`](https://valadoc.org/gtk+-3.0/Gtk.Menu.popup_at_pointer.html) to display a menu when the right mouse button is clicked.

When compiling (with `--pkg gtk+-3.0`), GCC gives me an error:
`warning: implicit declaration of function ‘gtk_menu_popup_at_pointer’ [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]`

The method exists in `/usr/share/vala-0.34/vapi/gtk+-3.0.vapi`, but is missing in `/usr/include/gtk-3.0/gtk/gtkmenu.h`.

Here are the versions of the relevant packages on my system:

```
$ dpkg -s libgtk-3-dev | grep '^Version:'       
Version: 3.18.9-1ubuntu3.1
$ dpkg -s valac | grep '^Version:'
Version: 0.34.4-0ubuntu1~16.04~valateam1
$ dpkg -s libglib2.0-0 | grep '^Version:'
Version: 2.48.2-0elementary0.4.1
```

**What should I do to be able to use this method?**

Comment: According to the [the documentation](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenu.html#gtk-menu-popup-at-pointer), that function was introduced in 3.22 (you're on 3.18.9).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your version of GTK+ is too old.

If you look at the GTK+ docs for the function, you can see it was introduced in GTK+ 3.22: https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkMenu.html#gtk-menu-popup-at-pointer, whereas you only have 3.18 installed.

Note also that the method is also declared as unstable, meaning that in the future it might change in a way that breaks your app, and hence you're probably better off finding an alternative solution for now anyway.